# pl/sql How to use for loop with cursor for update operation

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, cursor

I'm new in the PL/SQL and on a book I found this example about for update cursors

---

```
    declare
      cursor c_grade(i_student_id in enrollment.student_id%type,
        i_section_id in enrollment.section_id%type
      ) is
        select FINAL_GRADE
          from enrollment
        where student_id_id = i_student_id
        and section_id = i_section_id
        for update;

       cursor c_enrollment is
        select e.student_id, e.section_id
        from enrollment enr, section sec
        where sec.course_no = 135 and
        enr.section_id = sec_section_id;
    begin
      for r_enroll in c_enrollment loop
        for r_grade in c_grade(r_enroll.student_id. r_enroll.section_id) loop
          update enrollment 
          set final_grade = 90
          where student_id = r_enroll.student_id
          and section_id = r_enroll.section_id;      
        end loop;
      end loop;
    end;
```

My question is why do I need to use the for update cursor in this example? Which is the benefit compared this:

```
      for r_enroll in c_enrollment loop

          update enrollment 
          set final_grade = 90
          where student_id = r_enroll.student_id
          and section_id = r_enroll.section_id;      

      end loop;
```

Comment: for update lock(protect) rows and other transaction can't change the same  rows

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, [FOR UPDATE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/for_update.php) clause is used to lock the rows within your SELECT statement such that no other user will be able to change these rows (update, delete, ... etc.) until the lock is release.

The lock is typically released automatically once you issue COMMIT or ROLLBACK statements. This is particularly useful when there is a high number of DML statements running on the same set of data from different users. For example, you need to update the row with the highest ID at a certain moment, but before you update the row, another row was updated with higher ID by different user.

For your example, using

```
for r_grade in c_grade(r_enroll.student_id. r_enroll.section_id) loop
```

Will guarantee you are updating the version you locked, and nobody else has updated it before you.

You can find elaborated description with an example [here](http://oraclexpert.com/basic-oracle-dba/sql/for-update-clause-in-a-select-statement/)

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate your question, there are two types of locking mechanismm in Oracle

```
    1) Pessimistic Locking
    2) Optimistic Locking

    Optimistic locking is generally implemented by developers in the code some timestamp etc phenomena so that at one time only one user at a time can update a particular record.

    Pessimistic locking on the other hand (what you have used in the question) is the inbuilt functionality your database is providing to handle locking mechanism automatically.

Let me know if this clears your doubt on this.
```